# Больше установок за день при обновлении

Tags: мобильная-разработка, android, google-play

Статистика показывает, что при обновлении количество установок за день возрастает в 2-3 раза (а через 3 дня после обновления падает на прежний уровень)

**Вывод:** имеет смысл часто выпускать бессмысленные обновления?

Answer (score 2):

Не имеет. Частые обновления, не несущие визуально ничего нового, будут вызывать лишь раздражение у пользователей и, как следствие, занижение оценок. Мобильное приложение твиттера тому наглядный пример. Если уж очень хочется, то пары "пустых" обновлений в месяц более чем достаточно.

Comment: @falstaf, учитывая, что я в среднем делаю 1 обновление в 6 месяцев, пара пустых обновлений в месяц выглядит для меня достаточно частым. Именно такую частоту я и имел в виду в вопросе